# Is there a way to make infinate/loop horizontal scrolling CSS?

Tags: css, loops, scroll

Is there a way to create a horizontal scrolling that loops using CSS?

So when the user scrolls and reaches the end it brings back the start continuously like its infinite/loop or a wheel.

Is there a way of doing this easily using CSS and HTML?

```css
<style type="text/css">.auto-style1 {
  border-width: 0px;
}

.pagewrap {
  background-color: silver;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.scroll {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.auto-style2 {
  border: 1px black solid;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta content="en-gb" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>Untitled 1</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="pagewrap">
    <div class="scroll">

      <table class="auto-style1" style="width: 90%;">
        <tr>
          <td class="auto-style2">1</td>
          <td class="auto-style2">2</td>
          <td class="auto-style2">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="auto-style2">123456</td>
          <td class="auto-style2">123456</td>
          <td class="auto-style2">123456789</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did I get you correctly, that you want to basically reset the scroll position to the start, once the end of the scroll bar was reached?
I'm afraid, that's not possible with CSS alone. You would need JavaScript, with a listener on „scroll” events (bad for performance) or IntersectionObserver (perhaps not supported everywhere).

Comment: Not to reset to start but work like a wheel - continuously scroll repeating the contents. I thought so I won't be able to do it with CSS alone

Comment: Ah, so something like the (now deprecated) `<marquee>` element?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: Sort of, but its elements like the table I want in the scroll div, and to be controlled by the user, not automatically scrolling

Comment: Another idea would be to search for "slideshow", e.g. https://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/
What I'd do is defining the animation in CSS and use JavaScript to trigger it by adding a class.

Comment: Thanks @Ryuno-Ki that CSS slideshow looks interesting

Comment: Keep in mind, that it can cause problems for some people. That is, think about a presentation for `prefers-reduced-motion` media queries. Also, WCAG recommends to offer options to pause interactivity of those kinds of presentations. See also http://shouldiuseacarousel.com/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do this with just CSS.

One way to do it is by duplicating the children inside the scrollable container and jumping back to the left when the original children are entirely invisible.

I added some JS code to your snippet that duplicates your table and uses the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to determine when the original table is no longer visible and scroll all the way to the left.

```js
const scroll = document.querySelector('.scroll');

const table1 = scroll.querySelector('table');

// Create a copy of the table and adds it to the scrollable element
const table2 = table1.cloneNode(true)
scroll.appendChild(table2);

const options = {
  root: scroll,
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 0
}

const callback = (entries) => {
  if (!entries[0].isIntersecting) {
    // table1 is out of bounds, we can scroll back to it
    scroll.scrollLeft = 0;
  }
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
observer.observe(table1);
```

```css
<style type="text/css">.auto-style1 {
  border-width: 0px;
}

.pagewrap {
  background-color: silver;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.scroll {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
}

.auto-style2 {
  border: 1px black solid;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta content="en-gb" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>Untitled 1</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="pagewrap">
    <div class="scroll">

      <table class="auto-style1" style="width: 90%;">
        <tr>
          <td class="auto-style2">1</td>
          <td class="auto-style2">2</td>
          <td class="auto-style2">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="auto-style2">123456</td>
          <td class="auto-style2">123456</td>
          <td class="auto-style2">123456789</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works really smoothly. I was trying to avoid JS as I don't understand that JS you've written (but thank you so much), only JS I know is the basics - using variables to calculate numbers

Answer (score 0):

With css (and javascript) you will need to clone the element so it looks like scrolling for ever.

**Your answer stands here : [Is there a way to make infinate/loop horizontal scrolling CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60803720/is-there-a-way-to-make-infinate-loop-horizontal-scrolling-css/60804312#60804167) .**

here is a CSS example to demonstrate the idea , (using a shadow) and not a scrollbar , but the hover event:

Of course, this is for the fun of it, you will need javascript.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  width: max-content;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

b {
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

b+b {
  order: 2;
}

table,
td {
  border: solid;
}

table {
  box-shadow: 150px 0;
  animation: slide 2s infinite linear paused;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-size: 18px;
}

td {
  box-shadow: 150px 0 0 -2px white, 150px 0 0, 150px 0 0 2px white;
  text-shadow: 150px 0;
  padding:2px;
}

b:hover~table {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

b+b:hover~table {
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

@keyframes slide {
  to {
    transform: translatex(-100%)
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <b><</b>
  <b>></b>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

it could be done  **is not** it should be done ;)

Comment: That's very interesting. Thank you for that @G-Cyrillus

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addboxes(e){
    var categid = $(e).attr('data-categoryid') || 'a';
    //ajax cal here
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        for( i=0; i < 6; i++){
            $(e).append('<div class="box '+categid+'"></div>');
        }
        $(e).attr('data-loading',0);
        $(e).find('.box.loading').remove();
  }, 500);  
}

$('.infi-element').on('scroll',function(e){
    var lastDiv = $(this).find(' .box').last();
    var lastLeft = lastDiv[0].getBoundingClientRect().left;
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var loading = parseInt($(this).attr('data-loading')) || 0;
  
    $("#monitor").text(" lastLeft ="+lastLeft+", windowWidth ="+windowWidth);

    if( lastLeft < windowWidth-100 && !loading ){
        $(this).attr('data-loading',1);
        $(this).append('<div class="box loading">loading...</div>');
        addboxes(this);
    }
});
```

```css
.infi-element{display: flex;overflow: auto;}
    .box{background-color: bisque;width: 150px;height: 100px;margin: 10px;overflow-y: hidden;flex:0 0 auto;}
    .box.a{background-color:blue}
    .box.b{background-color:red}
    .box.c{background-color:green}
    .box.d{background-color:yellow}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div>This is content before comment</div>

<div class="infi-container">
    <div class="infi-element" data-page='1' data-categoryid='a'>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="infi-container">
    <div class="infi-element" data-page='1' data-categoryid='b'>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="infi-container">
    <div class="infi-element" data-page='1' data-categoryid='c'>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="infi-container">
    <div class="infi-element" data-page='1' data-categoryid='d'>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id=monitor></div>
<div>This is content before comment</div>
```